# Why is Hotspot throwing a pulseaudio exception?

Tags: java, ubuntu, pulseaudio

Okay I'm rather confused by this issue. I'm trying to run some proprietary software that seems to work for one person but not for two others. The software is throwing this exception:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
>       at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.Stream.native_pa_stream_new(Native Method)
>       at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.Stream.(Stream.java:263)
>       at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:132)
>       at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:100)
>       at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
>       at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:90)

However, as far as I can tell, I'm running Sun Java Hotspot. I'm on Ubuntu 10.10, which I know uses pulse audio as its default audio device, but when I tried switching to ALSA, I got the same exception. Since this code runs correctly on another computer, I assume I'm running into a configuration issue rather than bad code.

What might be going wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The pulse-java jni layer that sits between java and pulseaudio did contain some concurrency issues that have been fixed during the summer of 2011. Concurrency bugs usually manifests as race-conditions that only triggers on some machines and are generally hard to debug. Please update your distribution to Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric or find someone who can recompile (backport) openjdk-6 (6b23~pre10-0ubuntu4) for Maverick 10.10, this OpenJDK version have been patched to fix all known pulse-java jni bugs.